# Teamcity Clearcase Plugin tries to run update on a dynamic view and bombs

Tags: teamcity, clearcase

I'm setting up Teamcity 5 to point to a dynamic view. For whatever reason it has decided that my view is a snapshot (apparently without asking).

```
[09:27:38]: Nothing more to be cleaned. Build will be started as is.
[09:27:43]: update_clearcase_view
[09:27:43]: [update_clearcase_view] ccupdate
[09:27:43]: [ccupdate] cleartool: Error: 'M:\dynViewName\vobName' is not a valid snapshot view path.
[09:27:43]: [ccupdate] Failed executing: cleartool update -overwrite -ctime M:\dynViewName\vobName\build\..\..\vobName
```

How do I force Teamcity to know that this is a dynamic view?

Comment: Just completed my answer to illustrating the proper settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/279877), the root for the VCS view must be

```
 M:\dynViewName
```

not

```
 M:\dynViewName\vobName
```

---

In other words, do you have in your

```
Settings from the Administration > Edit Build Configuration > Edit VCS Root Page:
```

the following:

```
Type of VCS: ClearCase
ClearCase View Path: M:\myView
Relative path within the view: MyVob\MyProject
Use ClearCase: BASE
No Checkout Rules
```

?

If yes, it should interpret that as a dynamic view and act accordingly.

Make also sure the Vob is mounted in the server, for TeamCity to find the path.

Comment: With the greatest respect - I had  

    M:\dynViewName 
Is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Ok - looks like the Clearcase plugin for Teamcity 5.0 gets 'stuck' and doesn't read the new settings. Creating a new project solved the problem.